# display scroll bar for attributes under "shop by" in magento

Tags: layered-navigation, css

under "shop by" . "category", "gender" ,"age group" "price", "manufacturer", "brand".

there are lot of attribute values under "age group" attribute.

i want to apply a scroll box there , so i want to see only 6 values, if there is more values we have to use

"scroll bar" to see other attributes.

i want exactly like this:

http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mens-footwear-sports-shoes?

let me know if you need any clarifications....

please help me to find solution....

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belong to the topic CSS, JavaScript and not about Magento

Comment: hi, can you please help  me to get an answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
dl#narrow-by-list dd >ol {
max-height: 150px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It will apply the default scroll bar design.

In snapdeal.com, they have use some jQuery Plugin for Scroll bar

eg: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: hi @Meenakshi thanks for reply, can you please tell me in which file in which file, i have to place the code.

Comment: Any of your CSS file

Comment: i kept in skin > front > default > themename > styles.css file, seems it's not working, is anything else i have to do?

Comment: Skin>frontend>current package>current theme>CSS>style.css

Comment: yes, i kept there.... but no luck..?...

Comment: `skin>frontend>default>em0113>css>styles.css`
Add the code in this file. After that flush your **magento cache** and **Browser cache**

Comment: thanks again for helping me to  solve my issue. i will try....

Comment: yes, after flushing magento cache.... thanks a lot boss....

Comment: is it possible to give "max :height: 300px; "only for categories under "shop by"....